# Old School riddle with a twist

Tags: riddle, cipher, wordplay, lateral-thinking

Rhpeiwpa fj pejchao, ykt cqhh lb qdeo xjz iaoo
Qda pkhqpekj fo ewnikju, cnki tdwp tkqhz ya x jaoo.
Lnzejwh, Xxoyeoowh, xjz Fiiazewpa qnkqxha,
Znepeywh oareoekj jqopj’p oarawh x akqxha.

Hint:

> C22+1

Answer (score 2):

Partial:
Its

> Caesar Cipher with shift of 22 and every first letter as next one.

Rhpeiwpa fj pejchao, ykt cqhh lb qdeo xjz iaoo

> uLTIMATE iN sINGLES bOX fULL oF tHIS aND lESS

Qda pkhqpekj fo ewnikju, cnki tdwp tkqhz ya x jaoo

> tHE sOLUTION iS hARMONY fROM wHAT wOULD bE a mESS

Lnzejwh, Xxoyeoowh, xjz Fiiazewpa qnkqxha,

> oRDINAL aBSCISSAL aND iMMEDIATE tROUBLE

Znepeywh oareoekj jqopj’p oarawh x akqxha.

> cRITICAL rEVISION mUSTN'T rEVEAL a dOUBLE

Anyone can go further? I can't

Comment: Are those caps intended?

Comment: Just to differentiate the +1 done letters from others. @Nank

Comment: The small ones are those which have been +1 @Nank

Comment: hmmm, ok, sorry I got it now

Answer (score 1):

Long Shot,

is it

> https://puzzling.stackexchange.com

Rhpeiwpa fj pejchao, ykt cqhh lb qdeo xjz iaoo

> Ultimate in singles, box full of this and less
>  bunch of puzzles together(along with this one)

Qda pkhqpekj fo ewnikju, cnki tdwp tkqhz ya x jaoo.

> The solution is harmony, from what would be a mess.
>  if not formatted correctly, can go haywire

Lnzejwh, Xxoyeoowh, xjz Fiiazewpa qnkqxha,

> Ordinal, Abscissal, and Immediate trouble,
>  this I am stuck at

Znepeywh oareoekj jqopj’p oarawh x akqxha.

> Critical revision mustn't reveal a double.
>  possibly "duplicate" markings by moderators

Comment: Please hide the decryption. Thats half of it only

Comment: Nice try, but not the answer